# codeigniter pagination links redirecting to logout page

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm newbie to codeigniter. I'm using the pagination. The pagination links are shown fine but when i click on any of the links then i'm getting logged out.
Here is my code and please check if there any corrections needed

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Packages extends CI_Controller {

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();

    $this->load->model('admin_packages');
    $this->load->model('common_model'); 
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));      
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $this->load->library('common');

}


function packages()
{

if(!$this->session->userdata('userid'))
    redirect('index.php/users/login'); 
    $ofset=0;
$config['base_url']='http://localhost/index.php/vehicles/packages/';            
$config['total_rows']=$this>common_model>get_countt('packages_purchased','user_id',$this->session->userdata('userid'));
        $config['per_page'] = '10';
        $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
        $config['full_tag_open'] = '<p align="center">';
        $config['full_tag_close'] = '</p>';
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);  
        if($this->uri->segment(3))
        $ofset=($this->uri->segment(3)-1)*$config['per_page'];

    $uid=$this->session->userdata('userid');
    $bal=$this->vehicle->available_balance($uid);
    $arr['balanc']=$bal->mots;
    $arr['dtee']=$bal->dt;
    $arr['pack']=$this->common_model->get_alldetails('packages','status',1);
$arr['det']=$this->vehicle->purchased_packages($this->session->userdata('userid'),$ofset,$config['per_page']);

   $arr['page_title']='Reminder | Automated TEXT and Email Alerts for Garage Owners';   
   $this->breadcrumb->append_crumb("My Account<span>&nbsp;&#8250;&nbsp;<span>Packages", '/page');
    $this->load->template('vehicles/purchased_packages',$arr);
}
```

Comment: try leaving out index.php/ in your site_url() function.

Comment: what links does your pagination generate? Can you provide me an example of the final URI structure as it is on the website?

Comment: you should give us view file and generated links from pagination

Comment: Sorry guys, i have given the wrong page code.. now its edited one, please go through it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$config['base_url'] = base_url().'vehicles/packages'`

leave out the `index.php`

and if it redirects you to the logout are your sure that the session that is validating the current user is working?.

have you tried using `this->db->last_query()` to show how the query looks like?
because this piece of code here

```
if($this->uri->segment(3))
$ofset=($this->uri->segment(3)-1)*$config['per_page'];
```

will give you an offset of `90`

on your model `$this->vehicle->purchased_packages` add

```
$this->db->last_query();
die();
```

before the return this will print out the query you just made and you can see if you are getting the data you want right.

Comment: Dude, the equal sign was deleted while editing this question.... dont mind... the session for current user is working fine

Comment: and i've given per page variable as 10 but it showing 20 results per page... y this happening?

Comment: Don't use `base_url()` for links to your application pages, use `site_url()`.

Comment: `site_url()` takes your `$config['index_page']` setting into account. So if you need to remove your .htaccess and put `index.php` back in your URLs, all of your links don't instantly break.

Comment: @cyrode have you tried it? it still works  whether i use `site_url()` or `base_url` with `.htaccess` or with none, i won't post my answer if it does not work.